# Django: stripe must provide source or customer

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am new to stripe, I want to process the payment by stripe, and it show error:must provide source or customer. Someone can help?

Views.py:

```
def payment_process(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        order = Order.objects.get(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        amount = int(order.get_total() * 100)

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=amount,
            currency="usd",
            source=token,

        )

        payment = Payment()
        payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
        payment.user = request.user
        payment.amount = order.get_total()
        payment.save()

        order.ordered = True
        order.payment = payment
        order.save()

        messages.success(request, "Payment Succeed")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'payment.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use dj-stripe. It makes your life easier with web hooks, database management (as recommended by Stripe), and security stuff. However, taking a look at your code, your not using the stripe package correctly.

I believe you have to import stripe first and set the api secret key.

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = SECRET_KEY

stripe.Payment.create()
```

Additionally, the `payment.user` doesn't sound right... Check out the stripe api doc to see the correct attribute. You should be using the customer ID, not your user id. When creating a PaymentIntent object, you should specify an attribute `customer={{customer id}}`

Comment: I have import stripe already and set the SECRET_KEY, but there's no stripe.Payment for usage, only has PaymentIntent and PaymentMethod.